# Get all the data in a cell in Sframe

Tags: python-3.x, sframe, turi-create

I am supposed to find data related to a particular value given for a column. I am given the corresponding value in col1 and need the relevant data from col2. I ran the following code using turicreate.

```
sf1[(sf1['column_name'] == 'corresponding_value')].show()
```

After this, I get the "Materializing SFrame" section with the data in it. The graphs highlights show a small part of the required data from col2 but not all of it. I need all of the data. How do I print it?

(I can't attach screenshots of the incomplete cell data as this from a coursera assignment and I wish to avoid any academic dishonesty flags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: (num_rows = any number of rows you want to see)

```
sf1[(sf1['column_name'] == 'corresponding_value')].print_rows(num_rows=100)
```